# Using autocorrelation to measure a Markov chain's mixing time

Tags: autocorrelation, markov-chain-montecarlo

[This paper](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/papers/iMGPE.pdf) has a footnote that says

> The sum of the auto-correlation coefficients from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ is an estimate of the mixing time.

What is the rationale for this? The author calls this the "effective correlation length" in [another paper](https://www.seas.harvard.edu/courses/cs281/papers/rasmussen-1999a.pdf), but I haven't gotten much success in finding an explanation for this.

Answer (score 2):

This is a consequence of a CLT established by [Kipnis and Varadhan (1986):](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104114929)

> If the Markov chain $(X_n)$ is aperiodic, irreducible, and reversible
>   with invariant distribution $\pi$, the CLT applies when $$ 0 <
>   \gamma_g^2 =\mathbb{E}_{\pi}[{\overline g}^2(X_0)] + 2 \;
>   \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \; \mathbb{E}_{\pi}[{\overline g}(X_0) {\overline
>   g}(X_k)] < +\infty. $$ with $$ {1\over \sqrt{N}}\; \sum_{n=1}^N\;
>   \{g(X_n)-\mathbb{E}_{\pi}[g(X)]\}
>   = {1\over \sqrt{N}}\; \sum_{n=1}^N\; {\overline g}(X_k) \buildrel \cal L\over \leadsto {\cal N}(0,\gamma^2_g) \;. $$

See also the answers to this [question on X validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/110268/7224).

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not able to find the above in the linked Kipnis' paper. Is it somewhere around Corollary 1.5? Also, I understand that the autocorrelation sum appears in the expression $\mathbb{E}_{\pi}[{\overline g}^2(X_0)] + 2 \;
  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \; \mathbb{E}_{\pi}[{\overline g}(X_0) {\overline
  g}(X_k)]$, which is the variance for the limit of ${1\over \sqrt{N}}\; \sum_{n=1}^N\; {\overline g}(X_k)$, but how does this relate to the mixing time?