# Most common Markov chain CLT for Metropolis-Hastings

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, central-limit-theorem

Which Markov chain central limit theorem is the one most commonly used to justify standard error estimations in the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm? Is there one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave [this expression of the CLT](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/311229/7224) in an answer on X validated yesterday, coming from [Kipnis and Varadhan (1986)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104114929), which major condition is reversibility of the Markov chain.

[Chan and Geyer (1994)](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/~scs/Courses/.../GeyerConvergeMCMaxLik1994.pdf) have another version of the CLT for Harris recurrent Markov chains that are geometrically ergodic with a $2+\epsilon$ moment. (See also [Hobert et al. (2002)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4140533?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) for a reinterpretation of this result.)